# How to select from order model where order details parameter ? asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have Order model And OrderDetails model like that:

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int ShippingID { get; set; }
    public int SharepointID { get; set; }
    public int CallStatuID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   // public int OrderStatusID { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingCost { get; set; }
    public string purchasetype { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> orderdetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Shipping shipping { get; set; }
    public virtual Sharepoint sharepoint { get; set; }
    public virtual CallStatu callStatu { get; set; }


}
```

and

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int SizeID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int orderStatuID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public virtual Order order { get; set; }
    public virtual Item item { get; set; }
    public virtual Size size { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderStatu orderStatu { get; set; }

}
```

i want to select **Client name, Governorate, Total of the Order and Items count**

So i wrote this code:

```
public JsonResult ShareSearchDetails(SharepointANVM ANVM)
    {

        var SHR = from O in db.Orders
                  where O.SharepointID == ANVM.Id
                  join OD in db.OrderDetails

                  on O.ID equals OD.OrderID
                 
                  where OD.orderStatuID == ANVM.NameOfStutes

                  select new
                  {
                      ClientName = O.Client.RealName,
                      Governorate = O.Client.Region.RegionName,
                      Total = O.Total,
                      Items = O.orderdetails.Count(),
                      Orderstatu = OD.orderStatu.NameOfStutes

                  };
        return Json(SHR.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the problem is that the result is right, but its ordering by OrderDetails model.
that's the code get all rows from sub model (orderdetails) but i want it come ordering by Main model (Orders)

the result:[The wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IIYu.jpg)

but the correct Result should be like that :
[The correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK57r.jpg)

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Distinct` to get not duplicated rows, like the following code:

```
var SHR = (from O in db.Orders
           join OD in db.OrderDetails on O.ID equals OD.OrderID
           where O.SharepointID == ANVM.Id && OD.orderStatuID == ANVM.NameOfStutes

           select new
           {
               ClientName = O.Client.RealName,
               Governorate = O.Client.Region.RegionName,
               Total = O.Total,
               Items = O.orderdetails.Count(),
               Orderstatu = OD.orderStatu.NameOfStutes
           })
           .Distinct()
           .ToList();
```

Note that, you don't need to use `where` twice.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouping in your linq just like in SQL :

```
var SHR = from O in db.Orders                      
          join OD in db.OrderDetails on O.ID equals OD.OrderID                    
          where OD.orderStatuID == ANVM.NameOfStutes && O.SharepointID == ANVM.Id
          group new { O, OD } by new { 
            ClientName = O.Client.RealName, 
            Governorate = O.Client.Region.RegionName, 
            Total= O.Total, 
            Orderstatu = OD.orderStatu.NameOfStutes
          } into grp
          select new
          {
            grp.ClientName,
            grp.Governorate,
            grp.Total,
            grp.Orderstatu,  
            Items = grp.Count()   
          };
```